# app, built in android studio, not installed in android less version than 7.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i cant install any app that built in android studio in device with android elder than 7.0 version

my build gradle is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tests.ahmadkhan.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
```

the project is a simple project...
this doesnt works even in hello world project...

Comment: And what/how you are trying to install it? You cannot install apk used to instant run.

Comment: i tried to install it on android 6, but it didnt install again

Comment: i build and install on my android 6 device

Answer (score 0):

You have set minSdkVersion to 19, which means your app will work on api level 19 and above i.e Android OS 4.4 to 7.1 (assuming 7.1 is the latest version till today)

Comment: i tried to install it on android 6, but it didnt install again